# bottom align a button in R shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, fluid-layout

I cannot figure out a way to bottom align `downloadButton` with a `selectizeInput`, i.e.,

[image]

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    fluidRow(align="bottom",
      column(12, align="bottom",
             h4("Download Options:"),
             fluidRow(align="bottom", 
                      column(6, selectizeInput("plot_dl", "File Type", width="100%",  
                                               choices = list("PDF"="pdf","PNG"="png"))),
                      column(3, downloadButton('plot1_dl', 'Left Plot')),
                      column(3, downloadButton('plot2_dl', 'Right Plot'))
             )
      )
    ),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#plot1_dl { width:100%; vertical-align:bottom}"),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#plot2_dl { width:100%;}")
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
))
```

Placing `align="bottom"` anywhere and everywhere does not throw an error message, but does not have the desired effect either. Tried playing around with the style tags of the buttons, but well out my depth.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found an ad-hoc fix with `margin-top: 25px` in the style tag...

[image]

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
     h4("Download Options:"),
     fluidRow(
       column(6, selectizeInput("plot_dl", "File Type", width="100%",
                                choices = list("PDF"="pdf","PNG"="png"))),
       column(3, downloadButton('plot1_dl', 'Left Plot')),
       column(3, downloadButton('plot2_dl', 'Right Plot'))
     ),
     tags$style(type='text/css', "#plot1_dl { width:100%; margin-top: 25px;}"),
     tags$style(type='text/css', "#plot2_dl { width:100%; margin-top: 25px;}")
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
))
```

Comment: yeah I was going to suggest looking into this as the name of the selectinput 'File Type' affects the placement

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference for me when I try it. However, I'm using `uiOutput()`. Could this make a difference??

Answer (score 28):

Other way to do it is to pass `style` argument in the column function.

`runApp(list(
        ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
                h4("Download Options:"),
                fluidRow(
                        column(6, selectizeInput("plot_dl", "File Type", width="100%",
                                                 choices = list("PDF"="pdf","PNG"="png"))),
                        column(3, style = "margin-top: 25px;", downloadButton('plot1_dl', 'Left Plot')),
                        column(3, style = "margin-top: 25px;", downloadButton('plot2_dl', 'Right Plot'))
                )
        )),
        server = function(input, output) {
        }
))`