# Align widget buttons on same line in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, fluid-layout

I'm having issues aligning two input widgets in Shiny.

- Specifically, I can't seem to get a **password input** and an **action button** (generated using `uiOutput()`) to be bottom aligned in the same row.

My current approach offsets the two widgets:

[image]

when what I want is:

[image]

My code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           passwordInput(inputId = "answer.pass", label = "", value = "",
                         placeholder = "Enter Password for Answer")
    ),
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           uiOutput("actionBut.out")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$actionBut.out <- renderUI({
    actionButton("copyButton1","Copy Code")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

I've come across other SO posts and other sites that seem to have similar problems, but none of their solutions work for my example.

- [Bottom align a button in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28960189/4581200)
- [Shiny R Button Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28710027/4581200)
- [UI: positioning widgets (UI elements) side by side [Google Groups]](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/TnG5KCnaG3U)

**Can anyone suggest a *working* solution?** Thanks!

Comment: its the empty label for passwordInput that is causing the problems  `passwordInput(label = NULL, ...)` or adding `uiOutput(.., style = "padding:20px;")` will work albeit not relativly